# q-shifted factorial

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, q-series

Is their any formula to simplify

$$(a,ab;q)_n$$
where $(a;q)_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1−aq^i)$ denotes the q-shifted factorial.

P.S: $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.

I'm glade for your help.

Comment: $(a;q)_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1−aq^i)$ has two varibles: $a$ and $q$. What is then the meaning of $(a,ab;q)_n$ ????

Comment: @Fred $$(a,ab;q)_n=(a;q)_n(ab;q)_n$$

Comment: I dont think they can be "simplified". Observe that the normal factorials cannot be simplified either.